# Magento shopping cart rule for X+ items in cart

Tags: magento

Is it possible to have a shopping rule set like i want to give discount when there is a 
x+ items in cart.
It can be any items simple or configurable or grouped product. i just want to give discount when cart items reach to X number.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you got to Promotions > Shopping Basket Rules > Then create new rule.

under conditions set the following:

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
        Total Items Quantity  equals or greater than  3

Then under actions:

for the Apply dropdown: choose 'Fixed amount discount for the whole basket'
then below this add your percentage.

This is the basic requirement. There are more settings you can / tweak apply here.

Hope that helps?

Comment: How Can this be specific to any Group product?. i add one more condition like if SKU is --- to group product SKU, but as it is adding its child products to cart , it do not match the condition and discount is not getting applied.

I want to apply discount to group product with the condition like if x+ item is added from that group product , i need to apply some discount.